# Do we must to input type 'any' for every argument of the overloading function?

Tags: typescript

I want to understand, do we must to input type 'any' for every parameter of the overloading function. For exemple:

-we must do like this?

```
protected func(value: number): void;

protected func(value: string): void;

protected func(value: any): void {
    //...implementation
}
```

-or we can do like this?

```
protected func(value: number): void;

protected func(value: string): void;

protected func(value: number | string): void {
    //...implementation
}
```

If the second example is correct, the next question would be: does it a better way? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both work, and there's even a third option:

```
protected func(value: number): void;
protected func(value: string): void;
protected func(): void {
    let obj = arguments[0];
    //...implementation
}
```

(or `func(...args: any[])`)

As for what's better, it depends on you, your style and what you want to achieve.
In the example you gave I'd go with:

```
protected func(value: number | string): void { ... }
```

But for example with something like this:

```
protected func(value1: number, value2: string[], value3: () => void): void;
protected func(value1: { [key: string]: number }, key: string): void;
protected func(): void { ... }
```

It's easier to just use the `arguments` then to come up with a signature that matches the previous two.

Comment: As I understand there is no any difference and any 'Pitfalls', and my choice should be based on my convenience (should to choose more simple way).

Comment: Yup. There's no real difference.